# example of react-native multi-select with formik

Tags: react-native, formik, formik-material-ui

Does anybody have a working example of a react-native multi-select with formik? I already tried

```
import SectionedMultiSelect from 'react-native-sectioned-multi-select';
```

but the value array doesn't get submitted, but instead get an empty array.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there you have, hope you're reading the docs for both libraries. I'm doing that and it was just joining the code. it should work.

```js
// Formik x React Native example
import React from 'react';
import { Button, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import { Formik } from 'formik';    
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import SectionedMultiSelect from 'react-native-sectioned-multi-select';

const items = [
  {
    name: 'Fruits',
    id: 0,
    // these are the children or 'sub items'
    children: [
      { name: 'Apple', id: 10 },
      { name: 'Strawberry', id: 17 },                 
    ],
  },
];

export const MyReactNativeForm = props => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={{ items: [] }}
    onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}
  >
    {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
      <View>
        <SectionedMultiSelect
          items={items}
          IconRenderer={Icon}
          uniqueKey="id"
          subKey="children"
          selectText="Choose some things..."
          showDropDowns={true}
          readOnlyHeadings={true}              
          onSelectedItemsChange={handleChange('items')}
          selectedItems={values.items}
        />
        <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
      </View>
    )}
  </Formik>
);
```

Comment: That was it. Perfect. I was missing this

`onSelectedItemsChange={handleChange('items')}` :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is the example

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import SectionedMultiSelect from 'react-native-sectioned-multi-select';

const items = [
  // this is the parent or 'item'
  {
    name: 'Fruits',
    id: 0,
    // these are the children or 'sub items'
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Apple',
        id: 10,
      },
      {
        name: 'Strawberry',
        id: 17,
      },
      {
        name: 'Pineapple',
        id: 13,
      },
      {
        name: 'Banana',
        id: 14,
      },
      {
        name: 'Watermelon',
        id: 15,
      },
      {
        name: 'Kiwi fruit',
        id: 16,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    // next parent item
   ...
  },

];

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedItems: [],
    };
  }
  onSelectedItemsChange = (selectedItems) => {
    this.setState({ selectedItems });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <SectionedMultiSelect
          items={items}
          IconRenderer={Icon}
          uniqueKey="id"
          subKey="children"
          selectText="Choose some things..."
          showDropDowns={true}
          readOnlyHeadings={true}
          onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChange}
          selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ty, but I don't see formik here :)